# how to get back hamburg icon when set back icon?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

how to get back hamburg icon when set back icon? 
hen I am implementing change toggle icon when fragment on activity ,its set to back icon but need when its back the fragment then set it to again hamburg icon for open drawer of the activity,

**this is my code**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_arrow_back);
                //drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// show back button
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //show hamburger
                ///drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                //drawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment to show content and have the single toolbar inside host activity, you could manage your toolbar.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("First Fragment");
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.back_icon);
    }
```

Do not forget to call

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Comment: i cant understand your this ,bcoz i have only one toolbar that have in main activity,and when fragment have on that activity hamburg change to back arrow and when press back arrow then back to change it to hamburg